# What airport proposal(s) has London seen after WWII?

Tags: airport, aviation-history, airport-design

Instead of [Thames Estuary Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thames_Estuary_Airport#Maplin_.28Foulness.29) from Maplin in 70s to the latest inner Thames Estuary Airport, is there any proposal airport(s) raised after WWII but cancel/rejected eventually?

I know there is a airport proposal in the north-west London but it is cancelled eventually. Does anyone know about this?

In stead of these two, is there any other airport proposals?

Comment: I found the nw airport proposal in Cublington, Buckingham in 60s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was one more proposal before Thames Estuary Airport. That was the Cublington airport, which was rejected by planner [Colin Buchanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Buchanan_(town_planner)),as "an environmental disaster." Later the government rejected the proposal of this airport, and rather went for Thames Estuary.

Other than that, there are no more proposals for new airports, but there are certain plans for expanding existing Heathrow and Gatwick.

The Airports Commission says there is a need for one additional runway in the South East of England by 2030.
It has shortlisted three options:

- A third runway at Heathrow
- Lengthening an existing runway at Heathrow
- A second runway at Gatwick

Read in detail about all of them [HERE](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-19570653)

Comment: There's also the expansion of Southend's commercial activities.

Comment: Cublington airport in 60s is new

Comment: @Him Thanks  :)..